# Cannot perform 'xor' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python

```
dfUpdatedRPAPIData['0'] = dfUpdatedRPAPIData['Current EPS'] * (1 + dfUpdatedRPAPIData['CAGR']) ^ 1
```

When i used above line of code i'm getting error as below. Anyone please help me with this.

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'xor' with a dtyped [float64] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Please minimize the sample expression provided. Could you also provide inputs and desired output example?

Comment: dfUpdatedRPAPIData['0'] = dfUpdatedRPAPIData['Current EPS'] * (1 + 
                                            dfUpdatedRPAPIData['CAGR']) ^ 1                                                              
where dfUpdatedRPAPIData['Current EPS']=30.8500                                                
           dfUpdatedRPAPIData['CAGR']=2.618

Comment: Still not clear to me - what should the result be? Should the "^" operator do the "xor" operation or "power" operation? If really "xor" then how? Should each of the 64 bits of the float64 be binary "xor"ed with 1?

Comment: it should perform power operation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The power operation can be performed with `**` operator according to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-math-in-python-3-with-operators#power)

So your command should probably look like this:

```
dfUpdatedRPAPIData['0'] = dfUpdatedRPAPIData['Current EPS'] * (1 + dfUpdatedRPAPIData['CAGR']) ** 1
```